# is it possible to create a multilanguage installer using WIX?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, wix

is it possible to create a multilanguage installer using WIX ?

Comment: If so use this link http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson2.php#2.6.

Comment: yes localization but multi culture,
so user can select the appropriate lang. from combo Box before starting the installation process.

Comment: I think that this step is external to the msi. WIX is a tool to create Microsoft Installer databases which are msis. Since you should choose the language before running the msi it cannot be done with WIX. You can use install shield for this purpose or implement this step yourself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this without bootstrapper, if you create embedded transformations, and MSI installer will automatically apply one of them, according to your system locale.

For complete details & scripts, please, follow this link:

http://www.geektieguy.com/2010/03/13/create-a-multi-lingual-multi-language-msi-using-wix-and-custom-build-scripts/

They say, it is undocumented feature of Microsoft Installer, so please, be careful using it.

Comment: This worked for me (the windows 7.0 sdk vbs), along with following steps from [The developer's guide to wix 3.6](http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/9781782160427/ch12lvl1sec82) to make sure my codepage and productlanguage were correct in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

It may not be impossible, but it is likely very, very difficult to author an MSI with Wix where the UI language is determined at runtime. Wix is all about build-time localization, ie you can easily create different MSIs, each with its own UI language, from the same source files.

Comment: +1  Everything that I have seen shows localization done at build time, with separate localized MSIs being output.

Comment: But an MSI can have MST files beside it. The MST file transform the MSI to another language.

Comment: @Ikaso That's true, but I don't think it solves the OP's problem because you still need something external to the MSI to decide which MST to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a solution to your problem using WIX. What you need to do is to create a bootstrap loader. There is a tool called Setupbld.exe that helps with that. You can read more on [John Robbins' Blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20100408060142/http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/02/27/creating-a-bootstrap-loader-with-wix-3-0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. First, your .msi must have all the transforms from foreign-language MSIs embedded into it (see [Embedded Transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). This can be done with Microsoft's MsiTran.exe and [WiSubStg.vbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), mentioned in the [GeekTieGuy link](http://www.geektieguy.com/2010/03/13/create-a-multi-lingual-multi-language-msi-using-wix-and-custom-build-scripts/) elsewhere in this post.

Second, your .wxs file's [Package element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) must contain a *Languages* attribute with a comma-delimited list of all your supported locale IDs, e.g.

```
Languages="1033,1031,3082,1036,1040,1041,1042,1043,1046,1049,2052,1028"
```

Now you can double-click the .msi on a foreign language system and have it automatically come up in the correct language