# Installer with multilanguage support for .net applications

Tags: .net, installation

I have an application developed using .net that needs to be installed in different languages. The installer needs to prompt for a language at the start of the installation process with the default selection being the language of the OS, and then after selecting said langugage, the installer needs to provide instructions while installing in the same language and also install the application in the selected language.

Is this possible using Visual studio 2008 setup project or any other free tool? If not a free tool then are there any paid options. Please provide some links that show how this can be done. I've tried searching for this without much result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the Visual Studio Setup, however you can do this using the [Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), a popular free open source toolset for creating MSI based installers.

There is a similar question on this subject here - [Is it possible to create a multilanguage installer using WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340605/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multilanguage-installer-using-wix)

The linked solution - [Create a multi-lingual / multi-language MSI using WiX and custom build scripts](http://www.geektieguy.com/2010/03/13/create-a-multi-lingual-multi-language-msi-using-wix-and-custom-build-scripts/)

Comment: Wix doesnt mention how to get that drop down at the start to select language.. at least I am not able to see it in the documentation