# Wix installation

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

On the verge of giving up on Wix as an installer!

The things I want the installer to do

1. Prompt user for language selection
2. proceed with installation in selected language
3. skip the license agreement window
4. Prompt for feature list
5. Prompt for folder to install into
6. install application binaries in selected language
7. While un-installing, the language should be the language it was installed in.

Of the list above I have only managed to get point 3 to work. However I dont know if it is the correct way. There is no documentation I can find on what tag should nest into what tag. What the property ID names can or cannot be. As per the CHM guidance I have removed the license dialog and specified InstallDirDlg to be the next dialog after the welcome dialog. Inspite of doing that I cant get it to work. It completely skips the point 4 & 5 above and goes straight into the 'confirm to begin installation' window. Clicking next over there installs the product without even asking me which folder or which feature to install.

Questions:

- Does the UI and UIRef tag go into the Fragment tag or the Product tag?
- What exactly does one put into the Fragment tag?
- If I put the entire UI tag into the Fragment tags then the product installs without any UI. That cant be the correct place for it then. Right?
- Any other free installer I should look at to meet my installer requirements as above?

The full problem script file is here below as-is.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <Product Id="077765d1-236d-4299-b751-f921828f2ac8" 
           Name="A Wix Setup Example" 
           Language="1033" 
           Version="1.0.0.0" 
           Manufacturer="Study Products" UpgradeCode="1b0f72a7-8e17-4897-9f96-66509cc39573">

        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"  />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />


        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder"  >

        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="My Application Folder">

          <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="17e13748-8d44-47f6-b020-66d29f8a84fe">
            <File Id="WindowsFormsApp.exe"
               Source="../WindowsFormsApp/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApp.exe">
            </File>
          </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixSetupProject" Level="1">


      <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
        </Feature>



    <UI Id="WixUI_InstallDir">

      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

      <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
      <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Advanced" />
      <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" />


      <DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
      <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

      <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="3">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>




      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

      <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />




    </UI>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" /> 


    </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Thank you for installing [ProductName]."/>
    <InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action="CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" After="FindRelatedProducts">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallUISequence>
    <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="My Application Folder" />
    <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />


    <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerUser" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerMachine" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />

    <PropertyRef Id="ApplicationFolderName" />
    <UI >
      <Dialog Id="CustomBrowseDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.BrowseDlg_Title)">
        <Control Id="PathEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="25" Y="202" Width="320" Height="18" Property="_BrowseProperty" Indirect="yes" />
        <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="240" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIOK)">
          <Publish Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[_BrowseProperty]">1</Publish>
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
          <Publish Event="Reset" Value="0">1</Publish>
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="ComboLabel" Type="Text" X="25" Y="58" Width="44" Height="10" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgComboLabel)" />
        <Control Id="DirectoryCombo" Type="DirectoryCombo" X="70" Y="55" Width="220" Height="80" Property="_BrowseProperty" Indirect="yes" Fixed="yes" Remote="yes">
          <Subscribe Event="IgnoreChange" Attribute="IgnoreChange" />
        </Control>
        <Control Id="WixUI_Bmp_Up" Type="PushButton" X="298" Y="55" Width="19" Height="19" ToolTip="!(loc.BrowseDlgWixUI_Bmp_UpTooltip)" Icon="yes" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="16" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgWixUI_Bmp_Up)">
          <Publish Event="DirectoryListUp" Value="0">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="NewFolder" Type="PushButton" X="325" Y="55" Width="19" Height="19" ToolTip="!(loc.BrowseDlgNewFolderTooltip)" Icon="yes" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="16" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgNewFolder)">
          <Publish Event="DirectoryListNew" Value="0">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="DirectoryList" Type="DirectoryList" X="25" Y="83" Width="320" Height="98" Property="_BrowseProperty" Sunken="yes" Indirect="yes" TabSkip="no" />
        <Control Id="PathLabel" Type="Text" X="25" Y="190" Width="320" Height="10" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgPathLabel)" />
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgBannerBitmap)" />
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgDescription)" />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgTitle)" />
      </Dialog>

    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Sorry for the bad formatting. I fixed it the best I could. Thanks for taking the time to go through this...

Comment: Run away! - just had my first look and it takes 3 lines of xml to add 1 file. Can only imagine how painful it will be to do anything complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding languages, this question might help:

[is it possible to create a multilanguage installer using WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340605/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multilanguage-installer-using-wix)

The purpose of Fragments are to separate logical parts of your installer. It's not necessary to have a Fragment at all, but it can be nice to put, say the UI portion in a separate file. The reason it's not showing up is because you need to reference it from the Product portion.

These lines from your code are referencing a UI or Dialog elements from elsewhere, for example.

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
<DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
```

The other thing you'll need to do is reference your custom dialog in the dialog sequence. That might involve replacing `BrowseDlg` with your `CustomBrowseDlg`.

```
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

For retrieving the language, this post might help: [the WiX toolsets Remember Property pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern)

Windows Installer is pretty complex, but I can't say whether you would be better served trying another technology. Lots of people seem to like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) though.