# how to create language transformation that will correctly change the ProductLanguage property in Wix

Tags: wix

I have a MSI installer with some transform embed in it, I want to trigger this MSI with ProductLanguage property with multiply language like msiexec /i setup.msi TRANSFORM=1033, how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach which lets Windows Installer select the language automatically based on the target machine:
[is it possible to create a multilanguage installer using WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340605/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multilanguage-installer-using-wix)

If you want to let the user select a language, the only solution is a custom EXE bootstrapper. This EXE should display a language selection dialog and apply the appropriate transform.