# Change WIX Installer language at run

Tags: localization, wix, installation, windows-installer

Multi-Language MSI Packages without Setup.exe Launcher

Please help me to create multi language MSI package without  Setup.exe by using wix.

I have created mst file for different languages and embedded it with  EmbedTransform tool but it works only with command lint option like msiexec /i SampleMulti.msi TRANSFORMS=":fr-fr.mst". It was not working if I change language of my machine and install directly using msi.

I have followed below link from post but it also did not work 
[how to create language transformation that will correctly change the ProductLanguage property in Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832879/how-to-create-language-transformation-that-will-correctly-change-the-productlang).

It can also be fine if we can choose language from dropdown and installer language change according.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the directions as described on this site: [Multi-Language MSI Packages without Setup.exe Launcher](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/)

Steps described shortly:

- You create a basic MSI-package with English as default / fallback language
- You create transforms for every other language you want to include
- You embed those transforms within your MSI-package (so you basically just have **one** MSI-file)
- You adjust the Summary Information Stream

The scripts used are taken from the Windows SDK. Using this method you start the MSI and based on the **regional options** (**not** the UI language) configured for your system, Windows Installer will present the installation in the related language (if a transform was included) or in English (if Windows Installer couldn't find any appropriate language transform).

Used it myself with 5 languages included and worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! I have tested for German and It is working fine. I will do test further and let post if I will have any issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's an undocumented unsupported feature, be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer to [is it possible to create a multilanguage installer using WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340605/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multilanguage-installer-using-wix/28312305) on how to create an auto-detecting MSI. (I'd post a comment but I don't have the privilege.)

Answer (score 0):

Transforms must be applied when the MSI is launched, that's the bottom line. The language of the machine is also not relevant - if you have a separate exe to launch the MSI then the system language would be a useful default language, but there's nothing to stop anyone installing an English language MSI on a German language OS. And how can Windows know which transform files you have and automatically apply them during an install.

It's still true that if you want the user to select the language you need a launch program that adds the relevant transform in the MSI launch command line. Why is the separate exe a big issue?

Comment: Thanks! Customer want msi installer because exe may be restricated in their network or they concern about security.

Comment: Yes, it is right that there is nothing to stop English language MSI on a German language OS but it does not fulfilled localisation purpose if he want application to be in German language. is it possible with msi installer that it provide list box of language and then change installation language accordingly ?

Comment: Currently, I am using exe launcher that read machine language and call msi installer with transform but customer want msi so I want to fulfilled that requirement with MSI installer.