# how to create a localized windows installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield

How do I create a localized windows installer package for my WPF application, it has support for 6 languages and I want to have EULA document being localized when user installs the application

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged Wix and InstallShield, so maybe you are open to try other tools too. [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) (disclaimer, I work on its development) has in the [Professional edition](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/purchase.html) support for multilingual packages.

You just select the languages desired from Translations page, then go to Dialogs page and add a new predefined dialog, select "LicenseAgreementDlg". Advanced Installer will see that you have multiple languages in the package so it will ask you select the EULA file for each language. In roughly 10 minutes you will get your first installer up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite up to speed on WIX and localization (language support). This online tutorial is a good starting point for you: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/do-you-speak-english . Just read through the different User Interface sections.

I don't know which bundling you intend, but in my experience a **multi-language setup** is less desirable than compiling **one MSI file per language**. This is easier and faster to compile and work with (very important for large packages), more flexible if you need to bug fix something in a single language, allows you to add new languages easily without full UAT for all languages, and you can deliver the English version as soon as the code is done without waiting several days or weeks for localized files (if any are required).

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use Windows Installer XML, you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22405700/1785391). Note that the method is undocumented and not supported by Microsoft, however MS uses it itself and it is working very well.
Just provide a different file for every language transform to the WixVariable `WixUILicenseRtf`.