# C# Build installer project with dynamic application name

Tags: c#, windows-installer

We are having an application which should be built and cloned into multiple applications with different names. For example, for client A, we need to have an installer for that client with named "A Integration", but for B, it should be "B Access Integration".
However, the vdproj's application name should be configure manually using Visual Studio. Each time we need to have an installer for specific client, we have to go to visual studio, configure then re-build.
Is there any other way to do such thing? May be a command line as below is great:

`devenv.exe /Build myinstallerproj.vdproj /ApplicationName "An app name"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

People do this kind of text substitution with transforms, not at build time. It's the same general issue as localization for different languages. In the simple case you build the MSI for A with A's product name. Then edit the MSI with Orca or an automated script (see Windows Installer SQL) to build a transform, a .mst file. The A installs normally, B install with a transform on the command line.

See this:

[Change WIX Installer language at run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381811/change-wix-installer-language-at-run)

and in WiX:

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/transforms/morphing-installers/