# Choosing language manually in multi-language WiX installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, prism, multilingual, regional-settings

I would like to build a multi-language installer for my App which is currently available in English and German.
I will make the English Installer default and use a transform for the German Installer.

Instead of the Regional Settings automatically deciding the language of the installer, would it be possible to have a dialog box with the option to select the language?

Eg: As user in Switzerland, even though his regional settings are German should be able to install the English App without changing his regional settings.

Comment: This was the same question, wasn't it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340605/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multilanguage-installer-using-wix  Maybe you need to modify the installer UI and manually add a new Dialog for selecting language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom executable to run before the MSI executes to select the appropriate language transform to apply.

Comment: Will the custom executable then work together with the bootstrapper which needs to install many prerequisites?

Comment: If you have a bootstrapper, that could be your custom executable.