# wix localized installer UI load language by format?

Tags: localization, wix, installation, windows-installer

I keep my system locale as English and changed the Format to German, but the Wix installation process changed to German! How can I keep the Wix installation language as English (as the system locale)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to specify just the en-us culture when building

For Example

```
light.exe myinstaller.wixobj -cultures:en-us -ext WixUIExtension -out myinstaller-en-us.msi
```

See [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/specifying_cultures_to_build.html) for more information as well as how to specify the culture in Visual Studio

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for sharing the information.
I need multiple languages installer. But I don't want the installer choose language by Format. language should be chosen by OS locale, right?

Comment: You might have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340605/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multilanguage-installer-using-wix looks like it's an undocumented feature of MSI. Might be easier to just build multiple installers for each target language.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Actually I've created the multiple language installer. And I came across the issue because of the multiple language installer. It seem the installer choose language by Format. I don't like this language choosing logic.